# Python -- Generating values from a normal (truncated at 0) distribution

Tags: python, random, numpy, scipy, normal-distribution

I'm a pretty new Python user. I am looking to generated a single number from a normal (truncated at 0) distribution with mean mu, and variance sigma^2. I took a look at this:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.truncnorm.html

...but I'm not entirely sure what code I need to use, or the proper syntax. What if I want it truncated on the left side (at 0), but open ended at the right? What value would I specify for b?

Answer (score 2):

From the [definitions of `a` and `b`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.truncnorm.html) it follows that the correct values for your case are zero and positive infinity:

```
a, b = 0, numpy.inf
```

Setting `b` to `None`, as is omitting it altogether, [has the same effect](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py#L1415). (Thanks @Zhenya!)

Comment: Moreover, `b=inf` is the default, https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py#L1415

Comment: @Zhenya: Thanks for this. I've incorporated this into the answer.